# Fixing drifting and warping in tissue samples

Tags: images, image-processing, algorithms

I've got a set of slides that have been imaged under a microscope. The tissue on the slide floats on a water bath prior to being picked up by the glass.

For example:

[image]

In this image, you can see how the various pieces of tissue drifted apart from each other before they were picked up on the glass slide.

I'm looking for a tool that could automatically "de-drift" the tissue, effectively removing the gaps between the various sections.

An additional complication is that the tissue can also warp. For example:

[image]

I'd like to toss these images at an application (in Linux) that could attempt to correct the issues illustrated above.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's no out-of-the-box solution for this. I'd be happy with recommendations of specific APIs that I could leverage to write a custom application.